# Model fitting random data as well as highly correlated data

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, tensorflow2.0

I have a TensorFlow program that tries to predict a person's `total compensation` based on their `salary`. The program's accuracy tops out at about $65,000 mean squared error.

This level of inaccuracy was strange because `salary` is highly correlated with `total compensation` in my data set. So, I decided to change `salary` to random numbers. My model still topped out at $65,000 mean squared error. Why is my highly correlated input giving results on par with random numbers?

Here is my program:

```
DATA = pd.read_csv ('compensation.csv')

GOAL = DATA['Total Compensation']
INPUT_DATA = (DATA['Salaries'])

model_inputs = tf.keras.Input (shape=(1))
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense (20, activation=tf.nn.relu) (model_inputs)
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense (50,activation='softmax') (x)

outputs = tf.keras.layers.Dense (1) (x)

my_model = tf.keras.Model (inputs=model_inputs, outputs=outputs)

my_model.compile (loss=tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredLogarithmicError(), optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=.1), metrics=tf.metrics.MeanAbsoluteError())

my_model.fit (x=INPUT_DATA,y=GOAL,batch_size=1000,epochs=1000)
```

Comment: Why do you have a hidden layer with a softmax activation? That is very unusual

Comment: No reason other than the fact that other activation functions produced the same result. No matter what data I feed the model, the mean squared error peters out at about $65,000.

Comment: Another thing that makes me think softmax isn't causing this problem: when I call ```my_model.predict```, the model predicts ```97889.68``` dollars, no matter what amount I ask the model to predict for.